# Select a certain amount of checkbox arrays on the page

Tags: php, javascript, loops, onclick, checkbox

so i wrote a function to select a certain amount of checkboxes on the page, the number retrieves fine when i message box it but no checkboxes are checked.

here is my function

```
function checkAmount(number)  
{  
alert(number);      
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");  
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {  
    if (boxes[i].name == "vote[]") {  
        boxes[i].checked = true;  
    }  
}  
}
```

and here is my execution code

```
 OnClick="checkAmount(document.getElementById(\'ammount\').value)"
```

Comment: Just a note; You don't need to escape the single quotes in the `onclick` attribute value since you're using double quotes for the string.

Comment: i do since its executing in php and my echo is like echo' ';

Comment: above code will check all the checkboxes with name vote[] if present in the current document, is that what you want to do?

Comment: Please don't provide PHP code when asking about JavaScript problems.

Comment: wait PHP? how does PHP get involved in this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using document.getElementsByTagName("input") and this will return input elements which need not be check boxes alone.
Change your script to as follows:

```
function checkAmount(number) {  
    alert(number);      
    var boxes = document.getElementsByName("vote[]");  
    var len = (number>boxes.length)? boxes.length: number;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
       boxes[i].checked = true;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: thanks cybernate, you are as always .... awesome, ill accept the answer as soon as i can <3

Answer (score -1):

```
if(boxes.item(i).name == 'vote[]'){ ... }
```

and

```
boxes.item(i).checked = true;
```

Comment: Downvote for `item(i)` notation, or failure to point out `getElementsByName("vote[]")`?